# Redirected to a different question after logging in

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, redirection

I started here:
[Compound primary key in Table type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420897/compound-primary-key-in-table-type-variable)

Then I decided to upvote the answer, and clicked the "login or register" link in the pop up and logged in via Google.

I got back to [Compound primary key in Table type variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420897/compound-primary-key-in-table-type-variable)
then got immediately redirected on to

[More Primary / Auto-adding unique IDs per one table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613386/more-primary-auto-adding-unique-ids-per-one-table-in-mysql)

Comment: This was the top "related" post, so it is possible I clicked it, but I'm not aware of doing so, or even having my mouse in that portion of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what our http logs show:

```
CreationDate             Resp  Meth  Uri
2012-02-16 22:21:44.097  302   GET   /users/authenticate  --where you came back from google
2012-02-16 22:21:44.097  200   GET   /questions/1420897/compound-primary-key-in-table-type-variable
2012-02-16 22:21:44.420  200   GET   /questions/613386/more-primary-auto-adding-unique-ids-per-one-table-in-mysql
```

The `200` response on the first question means that your comment is probably true: you accidentally clicked the top related post.